# What is the Right way to pass credentials to python libraries like adls-fsspec?

Tags: python, blob, fsspec

I am trying to connect to a azure blob storage to retireve a file while trying to implement chunking using pandas. My question is if i use

```
pandas.readcsv('az://mycontainerpath',storage_options={acc_name, cred_string})
where the storage options are in env vars
```

to read the file instead of the

azure-storage-blobs libraries

```
CcontainerClient(creds and details to establish connection)
data = container_client.download_blob()
pandas.readcsv(data)
```

how do i understand the security implementation of how they process the credentials or do i need to even consider that point?.

Because azure-storage-blobs is maintained by Microsoft compared to adls which is done by individual parties?

I am a bit newto this so wanted some advice on what things i should be concerned about in same.What are the things one needs to consider when working with these.

Comment: If you are downvoting please do let me know why?

Comment: The README at https://github.com/fsspec/adlfs has plenty of info on how to pass credentials either with storage_options or environment variables. You cannot do this with MS libraries alone.

Comment: Yes i under stand part my question is that how safe can we assume the. Credentials and account details to be in while kn transit . I mean if we use requests we use ssl certs usually right how does it work for fsspec i did not see any thing related to that or does it just use Azure DefaultCreds to authenticate using Managed Identitiy?

Comment: Corrections use SSL, so...